# launcher BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining

Tags: node.js, protractor

Trying to run a suite in protractor getting the issue:
[launcher] BUG: launcher exited with 1 tasks remaining

cmd> protractor conf.js --suite='SuiteA'

Comment: Can you provide more details about your problem and update it in your question? Thanks

Comment: trying to run suite with --suite option

Comment: when i am running protractor suite with --suite through command , getting this issue
while some of the suites are running or some of them opening the browser immediately it exists by throwing the above issue.

I've defined suites like this
suites: {
TestSuite: './specs/TestSuite.js',
NDCreationAndApprove: './specs/NDEnrollAndApprove.js',
CreateMRAndActivate: './specs/CreateMRAndActivate.js',
NDCreationAndReject: './specs/NDEnrollAndReject.js',
NDActivationAndLogin: './specs/NDActivationAndLogin.js',
NDActivation: './specs/NDActivation.js',
NDActivation1: './specs/NDActivation1.js'
},

Comment: @GirishSortur did you faced this issue while running

Comment: kindly update your question with relevant details so that another person reading it can understand your problem exactly and provide solution to it. Thanks

Comment: when am running the command protractor devel-conf.js. Thanks